# Modeling 1-n problem

Tags: .net, oop, c#-4.0, model

I have a database that looks like this:

```
Product: PK(ProductId), ProductName.......
Store: PK(StoreId), StoreName......
ProductStore: PK(ProductId, StoreId), Price, Quantity
```

Here I have 1-many between `Product` and `ProductStore`, and also 1-many between `Store` and `ProductStore`. When I create model I basically have something like

```
Product.ProductStores
```

and this creates a problem when coding UI (example would be databinding). WHen I work with model, Querying data will always return only one `ProductStore` in `ProductStores` collection, because I am always working with one store at a time (PK:ProductID+StoreId). I also need to ave common Product table for Stores, therefore the necessity for `ProductStoreTable`.

Is there a way I can represent Product->ProductStore in model 1->0..1, which is actualy in database 1->many?

Thanks,
Goran

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually deal with this by creating a Porperty on the Product called ProductStore that simply returns this.ProductStores.FirstOrDefault(). and on the set clears this.ProductStores and adds the new one, if they are not the same.